# Python timedelta error: skipping a day when trying to get tomorrow

Tags: python, timestamp, unix-timestamp, timedelta

I have the following code:

```
import time
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta


def getNextDay(last_day):
    #Returns tomorrows timestamp at two times: 00:00 and 23:59
    last_day = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_day)
    tomorrow = last_day + timedelta(days=1)
    tomorrow_start = datetime(tomorrow.year, tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    tomorrow_end = datetime(tomorrow.year, tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, 23, 59, 0, 0)
    return [time.ctime(int(tomorrow_start.strftime("%s"))), time.ctime(int(tomorrow_end.strftime("%s")))]


last_day = 1370054073 #unix-timestamp

print "The day is:"
print time.ctime(last_day)

print "The next day is:"
print getNextDay(last_day)
```

When I run it the output is:

```
The day is:
Fri May 31 23:34:33 2013
The next day is:
['Sun Jun  2 00:00:00 2013', 'Sun Jun  2 23:59:00 2013']
```

I cant find what is wrong since the `getNextDay()` function seems to be right: I want to get tomorrow from `1370054073` at 00:00 and 23:59. But it's skipping a day the output for the next day should be `['Sat Jun  1 00:00:00 2013', 'Sat Jun  1 23:59:00 2013']`

Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`time.ctime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.ctime):

> Convert a time expressed in seconds since the epoch to a string representing local time. If `secs` is not provided or `None`, the current time as returned by `time()` is used. `ctime(secs)` is equivalent to `asctime(localtime(secs))`. Locale information is not used by `ctime()`.

So when you use `print time.ctime(last_day)` you see the time based on your local time:

```
Fri May 31 23:34:33 2013
```

But, when I use it I see a different time:

```
Sat Jun  1 08:04:33 2013
```

You can get the actual UTC time as following:

```
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_day)
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 1, 2, 34, 33)
```

And, as you can see it is already `June 1` so your function is working correctly and it is not skipping any days.

Comment: That is surprising, I tested it in online server (http:// goo. gl/hz2KUS) and you're right. Thank you, @AKS